# Multiple commands in a case?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to do this:

```
 case $ans1_1 in
     y)fedoraDeps;;
      echo "something here";;
      make -j 32;;
     n)echo "Continuing"...;;
      ;;
     *) echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'";;
  esac
```

Where `fedoraDeps` is a function with `yum` commands.

I'm trying to replicate this with cases:

```
if [[ $ans1_1 = y ]]; then
    fedoraDeps
    echo "something here"
    make -j 32
elif [[ $ans1_1 = n ]]; then
      echo "Continuing..."
      :
else
    echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'"
fi
```

Comment: The `;;` ends a case. Don't put it at the end of every line, just the last one in each case. Just Google "bash case statement" for more details.

Comment: Complete guess, but have you tried using a single `;` to delimit commands in contrast to the double `;;` to end the case? Or, for that matter, letting newline with no `;` delimit commands, which I think it will in a script file.

Comment: I generally put the closing `;;` on a line by itself to make it stand out more.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`;` or line feed is used to end a command. `;;` is used to end the case branch. Just don't try to end the case branch after every command, and it's fine:

```
case $ans1_1 in
    y)
      fedoraDeps
      echo "something here"
      make -j 32 ;;
    n)
      echo "Continuing"... ;;
    *) 
      echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Will using ```LF``` cause any problems with portability? Will the script work in FreeBSD, Debian, Fedora, RHEL in exactly the same way?

Comment: This syntax will work just fine across all POSIX compatible shells. Whether FreeBSD has a command called `fedoraDeps` is another matter.

Comment: ```fedoraDeps``` is a function defined at the top of the file so it does not cause any problems, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Due to variations in shell behaviors I suggest using spaces before semicolons...
Single ';' allow for what you want.  Double ';' 'end' the case 'match', i.e.

This should work:

```
case $ans1_1 
in
     y) fedoraDeps ;
        echo "something here" ;
        make -j 32 ;; ## last command for case 'match'
     n) echo "Continuing"... ;;
        ## if you want a blank line then just use one
     *) echo "Answer 'y' or 'n'" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Inserting a space in front of a `;` should make no difference.

Comment: What shell fails to treat `;` as a control character, allowing it to be part of the preceding word?

Comment: Hmm reasonable comments; after ~30 years of working with many flavors of *Nix (or *Nix-like OSs & shells) my experience reflects things that I have encountered, i.e. if we limit our discussion to the current version of Bash then yes, the comments are valid and mine can simply be ignored. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
case "$1" in
        start)
            start
            ;;
         
        stop)
            stop
            ;;
         
        status)
            status anacron
            ;;
        restart)
            stop
            start
            ;;
        condrestart)
            if test "x`pidof anacron`" != x; then
                stop
                start
            fi
            ;;
         
        *)
            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
            exit 1
 
esac
```